# android google play returns test response without checking test accounts

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am currently working on testing the response, which is returned from google play 
when you have uploaded a draft apk to the market and I came across the following situation:

I uploaded an application which is still unpublished and when I wanted to test the returned test response from the licensing server I always receive the specified response in the dropdown nondepending on the google play account I am currently logged in with. I mean if I specify a gmail account to the test account I receive the test response even if I am using another gmail account on the device. I think I should receive NOT LICENSED if the gmail account I am using on the device is not specified in the test account in the google play account. I am clearing the application cache everytime.

Now I am a little bit confused if I publish the application will I have some problems with the license verification process. It is going to be my first published application that's why I am asking for some help. I have read lots of discussions and these in the android developers guide but I think I am missing something.

The version code is the same to the uploaded applications; 
The application is signed and everything is done according to the specification of the android developer's guide.

I will highly appreciate if anyone can help about this or can suggest a complete processing steps of testing and publishing an application to google play.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Test account for testing licensing properly, all other users will get status of licensed users because application is not yet published.

see this, it may help you

> Note: If a paid application has been uploaded to Google Play but saved only
>   as a draft application (the app is unpublished), the licensing server
>   considers all users to be **licensed users** of the application (because
>   it's not even possible to purchase the app). This exception is
>   necessary in order for you to perform testing of your licensing
>   implementation.

Here is the link

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I will return not licensed to all other users if I am in a test mode. I have published my application and the licensing api seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot for the answer. I found this a little bit strange and was wondering if the response is going to returned in the same way, but now i got it. I have read this overview, but perhaps I have missed this Note. I decided to publish the application and to see if the problem remains, but I saw the google play services processed the response differently. It is fine now.